# Prove $f(x) = \sqrt {\ln x} \ln (\ln x)$ is uniformly continuous.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functions, continuity

Let $f(x) = \sqrt {\ln x} \ln (\ln x)$
Prove $f(x)$ is uniformly continuous.

I'd be glad to get hint/guidance. I tried to follow the definition of uniformly continuous, but got stuck in the very beginning.

Maybe Lipschitz can come to the rescue?

Comment: Is the domain of $f$ the set $(1,\infty)$?

Comment: sorry for not mentioning, the domain is $(e,\infty)$

Comment: @Svinepels I assume you mean $(e, \infty).$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the derivative of the function is 
$$\frac{\log (\log (x))+2}{2 x \sqrt{\log (x)}},$$
which is obviously bounded in absolute value.

Comment: OK, Actually I thought about it, but how can you tell for sure it is bounded?

Comment: Because as you go to $e,$ it approaches a constant, and if you go to infinity, it approaches $0,$ since $\sqrt{x]$ is growing faster than $\log.$

Comment: Can I use "..is growing faster than log" as an explanation? is that a rigorous explanation? And by the way, if I was not familiar with this, is there an alternative explanation why the derivative is bounded?

Comment: @IgorRivin Why not mention that if the derivative is bounded then the function is lipschitz therefore uniformly continuous ?